# How to install new hardware drivers so when it is plugged in for the first time, windows will know to find the drivers automatically

Tags: windows, hardware, drivers

I want to be able to deploy a project to some of my users the requires a USB-serial adapter. The hard way is to give them the drivers and tell them to plug in the adapter and when prompted, they will have to locate the files manually. I don't want to do that.

Most install shields know how to do that automatically - you install the software, plug in the new hardware and windows will automatically install the correct drivers. This is the solution I want, only without an install shield. What are my options?

Comment: Why is this tagged with InstallShield if you don't want to use InstallShield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout:

[FAQ: Information about Driver Install Frameworks Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463086.aspx)

InstallShield has support creating installers that leverage DIFx ( Driver Installation Framework ).  If you don't want to buy/use InstallShield, you can also take a look at Windows Installer XML (WiX). It also has extensions that support DIFx.

[Drivers Installation With WiX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44191/Drivers-Installation-With-WiX)